# Pandas dataframe with a column containing lists : how to access elements "dynamically"

Tags: pandas, dataframe, list, lambda

In my dataframe, I have one column (Vector) containing some list of elements :

```
import pandas as pd

x1 = ['A1','B1','C1']
x2 = ['A2','B2','C2','D2']
                  
df = pd.DataFrame([['ID_1',0,x1],['ID_2',2,x2]], columns=['ID','Key','Vector'])

print(df)

     ID  Key            Vector
0  ID_1    0      [A1, B1, C1]
1  ID_2    2  [A2, B2, C2, D2]
```

I would like to add a new column (Value) that contains the element of Vector at position given in (Key) :

```
     ID  Key            Vector Value
0  ID_1    0      [A1, B1, C1]    A1
1  ID_2    2  [A2, B2, C2, D2]    C2``
```

I can do it "statically", for instance df['Value'] = df['Vector'].apply(lambda x: x[1]) to get always the element located at index 1 of each list, but I don't know how to reuse similar syntax to get it dynamically (based on Key). Thanks in advance for any hints !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Vector'][row['Key']], 1)
```

When you use `.apply` on an entire dataframe (`df.apply`) rather than a single column (`df['Value'].apply`), it feeds the function each row as a pandas series (when we specify axis = 1, otherwise it's each column), which lets you define functions that access multiple values in that row.

Comment: Thanks for the right syntax as well as the explanation about the apply.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["Value"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Vector[x.Key], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     ID  Key            Vector Value
0  ID_1    0      [A1, B1, C1]    A1
1  ID_2    2  [A2, B2, C2, D2]    C2
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for with the reuse of the lambda syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
df['Value'] = [v[k] for k,v in zip(df['Key'], df['Vector'])]
```

Or, with a vectorized approach:

```
df['Value'] = (pd.DataFrame(df['Vector'].tolist())
               .to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), df['Key']]
               )
```

Output:

```
     ID  Key            Vector Value
0  ID_1    0      [A1, B1, C1]    A1
1  ID_2    2  [A2, B2, C2, D2]    C2
```